# Connect to mysql remote server docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I am trying to connect to a RDS instance inside a docker container. I have tried to telnet in the host and everything is working correcting. When trying to do the same inside the docker container it returns this error:

> (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'xxx.xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com\' (110 "Operation timed out")')

The docker container has as base image alpine:3.7 and I have installed MariaDB packages (mariadb-dev, mariadb, mariadb-client).

I have debugged and I have narrowed down to a connection between container and external remote servers.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb mariadb-dev mariadb-client python3
RUN pip3 install <django-packages>
...
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # Run app and supervisord processes

CMD ["sh"]
```

Comment: How you build your docker container?

Comment: @jonhid edited question to show dockerfile.

Comment: Can you run docker ps and show results?

Comment: ```d11f57f6d3d4   image:1.0                        "sh"                     3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        443/tcp, 8080/tcp```